# How's the css tag "-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio" implemented in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, html

How's the css tag `-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio` implemented in JavaScript?

Comment: What do you mean by "implemented in Javascript"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood your question correctly, you can access this property in JavaScript using the following property of the `window` object:

```
window.devicePixelRatio
```

Answer (score 0):

Any CSS property has a corresponding property of the `style` object. This includes vendor extensions.

```
elem.style.WebkitMinDevicePixelRatio = "...";
```

Comment: That's not a property though, that's a [media feature](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#media1). I'm not familiar with how media features are implemented in JS.